# What's the deadline to request a ticket refund with KLM?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, refunds, klm

[KLM airline](https://www.klm.com) offers fully refundable tickets ("Flex"):

[image: IMG:]

What's the exact deadline to request a ticket refund with KLM?

---

Below is what I could find in the ticket policy (clicking on "Show more" when booking a  ticket. I've added the numbered bullet points for convenience):

> 1. Refund before the trip: Before the departure of your first outbound flight, you can apply for a refund at no extra costs if you cancel your flight.
> 2. Refund after the trip: After the departure of your first outbound flight, you can apply for a refund at no extra costs if you cancel your flight.
> 3. Refund: If you are not present in time for boarding, the ticket is not refundable and you are not eligible for a free rebooking.

The "Refund after the trip" in 2 contradicts 3 and the screenshot above. The "Before the departure of your first outbound flight, you can apply for a refund" in 1 contradicts 3 ("If you are not present in time for boarding, the ticket is not refundable"), since the flight departure happens after the flight boarding. This confuses me and I don't understand what the exact deadline is to request a ticket refund with KLM.

Comment: I disagree that #2 and #3 contradict each other.  #2 to relates to a multi-flight trip for which you took the first leg (or return flight where you took the outbound leg).  #3 relates to never showing up for the boarding of any leg - making that leg ineligible for a refund.

Comment: @PeterM thanks, got it, that'd make sense. I don't fully understand the concept of "refund after the trip": can we cancel any future legs or just the return ticket,  how do we know the amount being refunded and what happens to the luggage is one cancels the future legs while one has checked through luggage. I may post another question on it.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the rules are

1. Full refund if you cancel before departure of the first leg
2. Partial refund for the remaining segments if you cancel during the journey
3. No refund if you are a no-show.

I agree that the wording here is somewhat confusing. If in doubt, call KLM and ask.

Comment: Thanks, "before departure" means exactly before the plane takes off, before boarding closes or some other time?

Comment: In most cases you are officially a no-show if you a) haven't checked in at the check in the dead-line (typically T minus 1 hour) OR  b) you have checked in but have not boarded when the gate closes (typically T minus 15/20 minutes).  In both cases you lose the legal right to transportation.